# Mount bucket with gcsfuse in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I'm trying to mount a bucket in a container inside of GKE in Google Cloud, but I have the following error ... Any ideas?

```
gcsfuse -o nonempty --foreground --debug_fuse --debug_fuse --debug_http --debug_invariants --key-file=credentials.json bucket-example /tmp/test
```

Log:

```
http: ========== RESPONSE:
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 31
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: UploadServer
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin

{
 "kind": "storage#objects"
}
http: ====================
Mounting file system...
mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

**modprobe fuse**

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.64+/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.64+
```

**uname -r**

```
4.4.64+
```

THX!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add securityContext to the yaml of the container:

```
    image: example:latest
    name: example-name
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      capabilities:
        add:
          - SYS_ADMIN
```